# VMware shared folder not showing on Ubuntu guest

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-workstation, shared-folders

I am testing VMware Workstation Pro 16 on Windows 10, and the guest is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with VMware Tools installed.

I configured a shared folder in the context of `VM > Settings`; however, it does not show up in the guest virtual machine's directory of `/mnt/`.

Please let me know if you need more details, and I highly appreciate any hints or suggestions.

**A little more details about the settings:**

[This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2m3SPolbD4) was about VMware Player. So, I tried the settings on both VMware Workstation Pro and VMware Player, and the results were the same, not working. My steps are:

- In context "VMware Workstation > VM > Settings > Options > Shared Folders", configure the intended folder as "Always enabled".
- Power on the guest virtual machine.
- On the guest VM, look for the shared folder in directory `/mnt/hgfs/my-shared-folder/`, but it didn't work as described in the post.

In my case, the command `vmware-hgfsclient` was aware of the shared folder, but the directory `/mnt/` was empty, and there was no `/mnt/hgfs/`. See the screenshot below for more details.

**Screenshot:**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/work/Desktop# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
root@ubuntu:/home/work/Desktop# vmware-toolbox-cmd -v
11.3.5.31214 (build-18557794)
root@ubuntu:/home/work/Desktop# vmware-hgfsclient
my-shared-folder
root@ubuntu:/home/work/Desktop# ll /mnt/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 19 04:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 May 21 14:14 ../
root@ubuntu:/home/work/Desktop#
```

Comment: What are the settings?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @BlockchainOffice, and I have edited the post with more details about the test settings.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like system service `mnt-hgfs.mount` is not yet running on your machine.  That service has to be running --- your shared folders have to appear in `/mnt/hgfs` --- before you try to mount your shared folders anywhere else.  Follow these steps (as detailed in https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/74650 ):

- Populate `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-hgfs.mount` with

```
[Unit]
Description=VMware mount for hgfs
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=umount.target
ConditionVirtualization=vmware
After=sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount

[Mount]
What=vmhgfs-fuse
Where=/mnt/hgfs
Type=fuse
Options=default_permissions,allow_other

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- Whether or not `/etc/modules-load.d/open-vm-tools.conf` exists, add this line to it:

```
fuse
```

- Enable system service `mnt-hgfs.mount` with

```
sudo systemctl enable mnt-hgfs.mount # so that mount happens after reboot
```

- If not already done, in VMware tab for your machine > Settings > Settings > Options > Shared Folders  > (fill in information for Host Path and Name)
- Start the service

```
sudo systemctl start mnt-hgfs.mount
```

Then after your intended shared folders appear in `/mnt/hgfs/` you can try to autoboot-mount them elsewhere via `/etc/fstab`, or apply to them `vmhgfs-fuse`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1144979)

Comment: @Toto - done; essentially the same.  (The link is very much pared down to essentials, to begin.)

Answer (score 0):

VMware Shared Folders work with Windows guests. I have not made them work out of the box on Linux guests.

Try this article to see if it helps.

[VMware Shared Folders](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Linux/16.0/com.vmware.player.linux.using.doc/GUID-AB5C80FE-9B8A-4899-8186-3DB8201B1758.html)

I have VMware V16 Pro on Windows 11 with an Ubuntu 22.04 guest.

There are two ways forward I use (both methods).

(1) SMB from Ubuntu to Windows. This is easiest because Windows has SMB by default.

In Linux:   smb://192.168.x.y/folder/ and authenticate.

(2) Install Samba in Ubuntu. I did this as well. Configure it and then map an Ubuntu drive in Windows with File Explorer.  Samba works as well.

Here is a tutorial for installing Samba

[Install Samba](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#2-installing-samba)

```
1. Installing Samba

In the Linux machine, install Samba

sudo apt update
sudo apt install samba

Use  whereis samba to verify the install.


2. Setting up Samba


Make a directory to share:  mkdir /home/<username>/sambashare

Edit the smb.conf file:  sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

Add the following lines at the bottom of the file:
    
    [sambashare}
    comment = Samba on Ubuntu
path = /home/<username>/sambashare
read only = no
    browsable = yes

    Ctrl-O to save and Ctrl-X to exit the editor
    
    Restart the samba service:   sudo service smd restart
    
    Update the firewall rules if necessary:  sudo ufw allow samba

    
Setting up User Accounts and Connecting to Share

sudo smbpasswd -a <username>   and password

(username must belong to a system account or it will not work)

In Linux:

smb://ip_address_of_Linux/sambashare

In Windows:

\\192.168.x.y where this is the IP of the Linux Machine

Authenticate with <username> and password

Shows as sambashare in Windows Explorer
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this solution on VMware website:

- Open a root shell in the VM
- Make sure the /mnt/hgfs directory exists. If not, create it.
- Add the following line to /etc/fstab:
  `vmhgfs-fuse /mnt/hgfs  fuse defaults,allow_other,_netdev   0   0`
- Then reboot your VM. The shared folders should now appear at the mount point /mnt/hgfs